# PHP Send data entered in a form to an admin page

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm looking at adding a feedback form at the bottom of a blog I'm building.

I've created the form people fill in to submit comments as you can see below. The form is inserted into the shortcode [post_review] which I add to a page:

```
function post_review_shortcode() { 

    echo '<form action = "review_submitted_feedback.php" method = "post">'; 

    echo '<fieldset>'; // Form Opening //

        echo '<legend>';
        echo '<p class = "S1">To post a review please enter your information below and hit submit! when you are done.</p>';
        echo '</legend>';

        // Please enter your name into the field below //
        echo '<p><label>Name: <input type = "text" name ="name" size = "20" maxlength = "40" /></label></p>';

        // Please enter your email address into the field below //
        echo '<p><label>Email: <input type = "text" name = "email" size = "20" maxlength = "60" /></label></p>';

        // Please add your review into the textarea below //
        echo '<p><label>Review: <textarea name = "review" rows = "4" cols = "40"></textarea></label></p>';

    echo '</fieldset>'; // Form Closing //

    // Submit your information by clicking 'submit' //
    echo '<p><input type ="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Review"/></p>'; 

echo '</form>'; // End of Code //        

}

 // A shortcode has now been created. Add [post_review] into a page to add the above form into the page // 
 add_shortcode('post_review','post_review_shortcode');
```

What I am having trouble with is formatting and sending this data to an admin page I've created (review_submitted_feedback).

What I've managed to create so for review_submitted_feedback.php is below:

```
<?php 

echo "Name: <b>".$_POST['name']."</b></br>";
echo "Email: <b>".$_POST['email']."</b></br>"; 
echo "Review: <b>".$_POST['review']."</b></br>"; 

?>
```

If anyone can advise me what I need to add or should look out for in completing this process, you would be much appreciated.

Also I'm hoping later on to add the ability to approve (and post) the data or delete the data, so if anyone has ideas/pointers on that I'm happy to receive. :)

Any advice is welcome :)

Comment: Where is your `review_submitted_feedback.php` located? At present, depending on which page this form appears on, it will submit to a path relative to the current URL, for example: `example.com/` -> `example.com/review_submitted_feedback.php` or `example.com/page/` -> `example.com/page/review_submitted_feedback.php`. You should prepend your path in your `action` attribute with a `/` and then put the path to your `review_submitted_feedback.php`.

Comment: Currently review_submitted_feedback.php is in a back-end folder. I'm unfamiliar with your method you've mentioned above. I was hoping to have the review_submitted_feedback.php content appear on an internal page I've created in the settings menu on wordpress dashboard. I'll try your suggestion of adding the page info into the action attribute. 

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The problem is that your action only provides a file name without a path. The browser will simply append the filename to the current path that it's on. So if you put your shortcode on a page like `example.com/page/` then when you click submit, your data will be posted to `example.com/page/review_submitted_feedback.php`, which probably won't exist. I would recommend putting either the path to your PHP file in the action `action="/wp-admin/path/to/review_submitted_feedback.php"` or you can alternatively look to hook into Wordpress since it appears you're writing a plugin. No problem :)

Comment: Thanks Jon,  I would never have thought of that by myself.  And yes to be clear I am writing a plugin. I think I need to do some more research on 'hooks'. I'll try your initial method and see how it goes.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem, hope you manage to get it working :)